# Geo-coordinates on billing address for account object non-existent

Tags: standard-objects, geolocation, standard-field

I am using the built in geolocation feature for the account object to provide geolocations for my account, however on some accounts the geolocation is null despite having a valid address

To make matters weirder the map feature still works for the address.

I have tried deactivating and reactivating the data integration rule to have the location update but it has not caused any change.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain why this is occurring and help me correct this error,

In the picture below Address Longitude and  Address Latitude are formula fields which display Text( BillingLongitude ) and Text( BillingLatitude) respectively.

Thank you for your time.

[image: Image of description above]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check your address. There is most likely a typo in the street number. Google will still be able to show an approximate location of a street number despite it not being a correct address, because numbers are assigned based on the distance from some particular location. For example, an address like 1234 is about one third of the way past the 1200 block (away from the number source).

Comment: `Mulbery` vs `Mulberry` with two r's.